# Removing extra space between HStack and VStack?

Tags: swift, swiftui, widget

My text "Line1" has too much space below it. I would like to move the image up more but not sure how to get rid of all that space? This is for a small widget so would love to hear any advice on how to get it to resize properly for all devices!

```
var body: some View {
        ZStack {
                    Color("BackgroundColor")
                  
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Line1")
                             .foregroundColor(Color("Orange"))
                             .bold()
                                .font(.system(size: 17.5))
                                .padding(.top)
                             Spacer()
                        
                            Image("Icon")
                                .padding(.top)
                      
                        }
                        .padding()
                           
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            
                            Image("Icon2")
                      
                           Text("State")
                            .foregroundColor(Color("white"))
                            .font(.system(size: 15))
                            //.font(family == .systemLarge ? .title :
                                   // .headline)
                            .padding(.top, family == .systemLarge ? -15
                                     : 0)
                            
                            Text("Last update 4.16.2021")
                             .foregroundColor(Color("Color2"))
                             .font(.system(size: 10))
                                .opacity(0.5)
                                
                            Spacer()
                            Spacer()
                        }
                        .padding() 
                        
                    }
                    
                }
```

Comment: have you tried removing the spacer just above your checkmark image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your first `VStack`, you can add a `spacing` of `0`:

```
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
```

You also have a couple of `padding()` modifiers, that also increase spacing. You could change them to `.padding(.horizontal)`, which would remove that extra padding.

Sometimes, it's useful for debugging to put `.border`s around the different elements to see what's really taking up space. For example, here's what my debugging version looks like (note I had to change the image and color names and provide default sizes size I didn't have your images or colors):

```
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Color.red
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
            HStack {
                Text("Line1")
                    .foregroundColor(.orange)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.system(size: 17.5))
                    .padding(.top)
                Spacer()
                
                Image("2")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
                    .padding(.top)
                
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .border(Color.green)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Image("2")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 67, height: 30)
                
                Text("State")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .font(.system(size: 15))
                
                Text("1")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
                    .font(.system(size: 10))
                    .opacity(0.5)
                
                Spacer()
                Spacer()
            }
            .padding(.horizontal)
            .border(Color.blue)
        }
    }
}
```